# undefined appState on handleRedirectCallback - Angular Auth0

Tags: angular, typescript, auth0

I am trying to move our Auth0 to the new setup with Auth0Client. When trying to use the login, the page just reloads throwing in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
    at a (auth0-spa-js.production.js:1)
```

After a short debugging session I can see the line:

```
const result = await client.handleRedirectCallback();
```

Gives a result with an undefined appState which causes the issue (as the resolved callback url ends up in an empty string). The callbacks are registered correctly and the Client is fetched fine. What's the problem here?

Comment: Just to keep the reference to the question in the Auth0 community, here's a link: https://community.auth0.com/t/typeerror-cannot-read-property-close-of-undefined-when-using-new-auth0-spa-library-in-angular-interceptor/28010

Comment: Same error here. Does anyone have any theory about that?